# React: loading two different images for mobile and desktop

Tags: reactjs

Inside a React app, I need to load two different versions of the same image on mobile and desktop. Both images are long SVG files.
For this I created an extra component called **MySvgImage.js**, which contains the code for both SVG files.

Now inside another component, where I want to render the image, I'm importing **MySvgImage.js** and render.

But how can I show one SVG image for mobile and the other for desktop?
What would be a good approach?

Comment: usually you would media query and check the width. another option is the navigator api

Comment: I would suggest that you load those different image by using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) on different viewport. But, if it's a must to use React to control them, you'd want to spy on viewport's width and apply the image dynamically

Comment: Are you using any css framework????

Comment: The project is using only FlexBox

Answer (score 2):

you could use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive)

install it using :

> npm install react-responsive

an example of what you would do :

```
 
const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Device Test!</h1>
    <MediaQuery minDeviceWidth={1224} device={{ deviceWidth: 1600 }}>
      <img src="first image/>
    </MediaQuery>
    <MediaQuery minResolution='2dppx'>
      <img src="second image/>
    </MediaQuery>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but for future visitors, you could try the [Picture element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture). So your use-case would look something like this (using `@media` queries):

```
<picture>
    <!-- Desktop use-case -->
    <source srcset="/path/to/desktop.svg" media="(min-width: 1240px)">
    <!-- Mobile use case will be the default (could always swap them) -->
    <img src="/path/to/mobile.svg" alt="" />
</picture>
```